# Bootstrap 3.0 Modal doesn't render on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with the latest version of Bootstrap for my website (3.x or so) and I'm having some issues with the modals.

The login for my site is written as a modal, and when you click the link for it it will pop up and render 100% correctly on a desktop browser. However, when trying to access that modal on my Iphone browser, the modal doesn't generate at all: the link doesn't appear to do anything.

Here's what the code for the modal link looks like:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-box">Login</a>
```

Here's the modal code itself:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-box" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="login-box-title" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="login-box-title">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Content of the box goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the javascript files that were included in my bootstrap folder, along with Jquery 1.11.0, if that matters.

Here's a link to my site: http://obs.arbitratum.com (most of it is only built out on my local machine, but the login & register functionality works fine).

Comment: The login link works for me on Windows Phone 8.1 (IE11): http://imgur.com/dxflHUl. Which browser/device are you testing on?

Comment: Interesting... I'm testing on an iPhone 4s with the latest version of Safari. I've gotten reports that iPad's browser is having the same issue as well. I'm going to download chrome and see if it affects that browser as well.

Comment: IIRC if you have a mac you can access mobile safari's dev console from it and see if there are any JavaScript errors. It would be good if someone with an android device could test this too

Comment: I tried using the Dev Tools on Safari on a PC (with the user agent set to iOS), however the modal appeared to work completely fine there. Also, I installed chrome on my iPhone and tried it there, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I get this javascript error in the console when I launch a modal, perhaps the version of javascript I'm using for Bootstrap is out of date, or broken? `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function obs.arbitratum.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js:6`

Comment: The issue seemed to be with bootstrap.min.js and not bootstrap.js, so I removed the minimalized js version of the file. Opening the dialog box no longer generates a javascript error, however the dialog box still won't open on my iPhone's browsers. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Works fine on my Mac & iPad.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I managed to fix it around Noon today, PST. The issue apparently was that I did not add an HREF attribute to the <a> that opened the MODAL. Simply having the data values and no onclick or href will cause it not to render correctly on iOS.